# Snowflake; convert strings to an array

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using snowflake, I have a column named 'column_1'. The datatype is TEXT.
An example of a value in this column is here:

```
["Apple", "Pear","Chicken"]
```

I say:
`select to_array(column_1) from fake_table;` and I get:

`[ "[\"Apple\",\"Pear\",\"Chicken\"]" ]`

So it put my text into it. But I want to *convert* the datatype. Seems like it should be simple.

I try `strtok_to_array(column_1, ',')` and get the same situation.

How can snowflake convert strings to an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `PARSE_JSON`:

```
SELECT PARSE_JSON('["Apple", "Pear","Chicken"]')::ARRAY;

DESC RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since that's valid JSON, you can use the PARSE_JSON function:

```
select parse_json('["Apple", "Pear","Chicken"]');

select parse_json('["Apple", "Pear","Chicken"]')[0]; -- Get first one

select parse_json('["Apple", "Pear","Chicken"]')[0]::string; -- Cast to string
```

Comment: Why is it "valid JSON"? It looks like an array to me. I don't see any curly braces or key value pairs. That's really confusing.

Comment: The top-level of JSON can be a string, a number, an array, or an object. Curly braces enclose an object, which requires key/value pairs. An array does not require (or allow) keys, only values. This is valid JSON with the top-level object an array.

Comment: By that reasoning, I'm struggling to imagine anything that can't be valid JSON. How about an integer? Is that valid JSON?

Comment: Yes, an integer is valid JSON. Since an integer is a primitive type with no structure, you can't have anything else in the JSON except the integer if it's at the top level. You can test this at jsonlint.com

Comment: ok well that blew my mind. Everything is JSON but JSON at the same time is a very particular structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `parse_json` is the way to go, but if you're concerned some values might not be a valid `json`, you could get rid of the double quotes and square brackets and split the resulting comma separated string to `array`

```
select split(translate(col,$$"[]$$,''),',')
```

Note : Encapsulating in $$ makes escaping quotes and any other special character easier